# How to underline text with large font size in Swift using NSAttributedString?

Tags: fonts, swift4, nsattributedstring

I dont figure out how to underline text with large font size with NSAttributedString in swift 4.2

For exemple, this code is NOT underlined, but if i change the font size to 12 or lower, it work and the text is underlined..

How can i underline my text with a font size of 25 or higher?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let mylabel = SKLabelNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let myAttributes : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Regular", size: 25.0)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]

        mylabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World", attributes: myAttributes)
        mylabel.position = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 , y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
        addChild(mylabel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UnderlinedLabel: UILabel {

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = text else { return }
            let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.count)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle , value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: textRange)
            // Add other attributes if needed
            self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
}
```

After that directly assign the UnderlineLabel class to particular Label into StoryBoard.